# Defining Schwars rearrangement for other kind of symmetric domains

Tags: measure-theory, symmetry, symmetric-functions, decreasing-rearrangements

Given a Lebesgue measurable subset $E \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ we denote its $N-$dimensional Lebesgue measure
by $|E|$. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded measurable set and $u : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function.
For $t \in \mathbb{R}$ we define
$$
\{ u > t\} = \{x \in \Omega : u(x) > t\}.
$$
The distribution function of $u$ is given by
$$
\mu_u(t) = |\{u > t\}|.
$$
The (uni dimensional) decreasing rearrangement of $u$ is defined on $[0, |\Omega|]$ by
\begin{equation}
 u^{\#}(s) = \left\{
 \begin{array}{rcll}
  \text{ess sup} (u),& \text{ if }s = 0  \\
  \inf\{t : \mu_u(t) < s\} ,& \text{ if } 0 < s < |\Omega| 
 \end{array}, 
 \right. 
\end{equation}
Given $E \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a measurable set of finite measure. We define $E^\ast$, the symmetric rearrangement of $E$ to be
$$
B_R(0), R = \left(\frac{|E|}{|B|}\right)^{\frac{1}{N}}.
$$
Notice that $|E| = |E^\ast|$. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain and Let $u : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$
be a measurable function. Its Schwarz symmetrization or, the
spherically symmetric and decreasing rearrangement is the function
$u^\ast : \Omega^\ast \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by
$$
u^\ast (x) = u^{\#}(|B||x|^N), \quad x \in \Omega^{\ast}.
$$
I would like to know if is it possible to define Schwarz rearrangment with other kind of symmetriztion intead of a ball, for example, taking $E^{\ast}$ is a annulos with the same measure as $E$, in such a way that all the properties are preserved.